# Javascript - Spine MVC - Class

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks

I've been searching all over StackOverflow but i couldn't find an answer for this.

What's the purpose of the Class in Spine (MVC Javascript Framework)? http://maccman.github.com/spine/#h-classes

I mean... I've been reading the docs, but I can't seem to figure out a real-world example to use Classes, and every time I think of something that probably would be the right use for it, I realize that I'm just confusing it with the Model.

Would anyone be kind enough to explain me where would be fit to use the Spline.Class correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Classes - "At the heart of Spine it's it's class implementation which uses en emulated version of Object.create to ensure that it's both dynamic and that properties can be resolved at runtime." This picture explains it quite well: http://addyosmani.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/spinegraph.jpg And the full article, which is an interview with Alex MacCaw - Spine JS' author, can be found here: http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-apps-spinejs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes within Spine extend javascripts object model so you can use this when ever you wish to engage in object oriented design within your javascript.

I would suggest if you are not missing it you do not need to use it.

Just to be sure because I miss read your question on the first pass MVC is Model View Controller, so the important C in MVC is controller not Class.